# onCreate being called twice?

Tags: android

Using my mom's phone with my app if i hit the home button and then navigate back to the app, it is calling onCreate again. If I understand correctly this should not be the case right?

I know this is happening because my webview loads and it should just open up the page that was already open. Especially since I have the launch mode set to singleInstance...

What are some reasons to why it would be called twice on my mom's phone, but on my phone it works exactly how it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), your Activity can be killed at any time when it's not active which is the case when you switch back to the home screen.

> If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity
>   from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its
>   process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely
>   restarted and restored to its previous state.

Comment: so when this happens is it calling the onDestroy() method or the onStop() method because when my onCreate is called I am losing control of my mediaplayer and cannot stop the music that is playing.

Comment: Android will at least call onPause() when you leave the Activtiy, after that the Activity is paused and might be killed at any time. What do you mean by losing control? Are you playing audio in an Activity? Just in case: Services are made just for stuff like playing audio.

Comment: I am playing mediaplayer when a person click an mp3 link. I couldnt figure out how to pass the url into the mediaplayer through a service so i have a notification as a service and the mediaplayer is just a part of shouldoverrideurlloading

Comment: You really want to do this in a Service, for more details I'd recommend the [dev guide on services](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).